# How to update ListView entries and let the user continue and scrolling the listview values?

Tags: android, android-listview

I am trying to  update the list of listView while the user is scrolling the list and give the user the option to continue and scrolling the new entries but with no success and i need an help.

In my application, i have a chat and i am saving history of the chat at SQLite. when the user is entered to the chat, the application is reading only the last 25 message and present the newest message at the bottom of the list. 
In order that do that i am using the following options at the XML:

```
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
```

and it is working fine.
Now , when the user is starting to scroll up and checking the history of the chat, when he is arriving to the top of the list, i am accessing the database and retrieving another 25 messages and add them to the top of the list and i am calling to: 
        chatAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();

but when the user is trying to scroll up, nothing is presented, only after scrolling down and up again the new entries are presented.

I have try to set the position of the list view using setSelection and smoothScrollToPosition but it is not really work.

how can it update the list with new entries and give the user the option to continue and scroll up?

here is the relevant code:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/chatList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/frame_tab"></ListView>


public void showChatLines() {

    chatLinesView = chatTextDialog.findViewById(R.id.chatList);

    chatAdaptor = new GenericAdapter<ChatLine>(activity, chatLines) {
        @Override
        public View getMyView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent, ChatLine chatLine) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_line, null);

            TextView chatLineText = view.findViewById(R.id.chatLine);
            chatLineText.setText(chatLine.messageText);
            TextView chatLineTime = view.findViewById(R.id.chatLineTime);
            chatLineTime.setText(chatLine.displayDateTime);
            TextView chatLineUserName = view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            chatLineUserName.setText(chatLine.userDisplayName);
            chatLineUserName.setTextColor(activity.getColor(Constants.colors[getColorBy(chatLine.userName)]));

            LinearLayout chatLineLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.chatLineLayout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams chatLineLayoutParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) chatLineLayout.getLayoutParams();
            CardView chatLineBackground = view.findViewById(R.id.chatLineBackground);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams chatLineBackgroundParams = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) chatLineBackground.getLayoutParams();
            LinearLayout chatLineSubLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.chatLineSubLayout);
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams chatLineSubLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) chatLineSubLayout.getLayoutParams();

            if (chatLine.userName.equals(logonUserName)) {
                CardView charLineCard = view.findViewById(R.id.chatLineBackground);
                charLineCard.setCardBackgroundColor(activity.getColor(R.color.focusedColor));
                ((ViewGroup) chatLineUserName.getParent()).removeView(chatLineUserName);
            } else {
                chatLineLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                chatLineLayout.setLayoutParams(chatLineLayoutParams);
                chatLineSubLayoutParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                chatLineSubLayout.setLayoutParams(chatLineSubLayoutParams);
                chatLineBackgroundParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                chatLineBackground.setLayoutParams(chatLineBackgroundParams);
            }

            if (position==0 & fromLine!=0) {
                getNextChatLinesFromDb(position);
            }
            return view;
        }
    };

    chatLinesView.setAdapter(chatAdaptor);

}

private void getNextChatLinesFromDb(int position) {
    toLine = fromLine - 1;
    fromLine -= pageSize;
    if (fromLine < 0) {
        fromLine = 0;
    }
    ArrayList<ChatLine> newChatLines = db.getChatLines(chatRoomId, fromLine, toLine);
    chatLines.addAll(0, newChatLines);
    chatAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: could you please post your code ?

Comment: i have added the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below sample code:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener{

final static private int ADD_DATA_SIZE = 10;

ArrayList<String> dataList;
ListView listView;
ArrayAdapter adapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
        dataList.add("Item " + i);
    }
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i) + " Clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    listView.setOnScrollListener(this);
}

private void addNewData() {
    ArrayList<String> tmpList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<ADD_DATA_SIZE; i++){
        tmpList.add("Add " + (dataList.size() - 20)/10 + ": Item " + i);
    }
    dataList.addAll(0, tmpList);

    // Try this:
    //listView.setSelection(ADD_DATA_SIZE);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    // or this:
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listView.setSelection(ADD_DATA_SIZE);

}

@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {}

@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem,
                     int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    if(firstVisibleItem == 0){
        View view = absListView.getChildAt(0);
        if(view != null){
            if (view.getTop() == absListView.getTop()) {
                absListView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_DISABLED);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRANSCRIPT MODE CHANGED TO: "
                        + absListView.getTranscriptMode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                addNewData();
            }
        }
    } else if (totalItemCount == (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount)){
        View view = absListView.getChildAt(visibleItemCount - 1);
        if (view.getBottom() == absListView.getBottom()) {
            absListView.setTranscriptMode(AbsListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TRANSCRIPT MODE CHANGED TO: "
                    + absListView.getTranscriptMode(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

i think this code will help you :

```
// get position of listview
int index = chatLinesView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
View v = chatLinesView.getChildAt(0);
int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

// notify dataset changed or re-assign adapter here

//re-assign the position of listview after setting the adapter again
chatLinesView.setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
```

**edit**

```
int h1 = chatLinesView.getHeight();
int h2 = chatLinesViewRow.getHeight();

chatLinesView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(position, h1/2 - h2/2, duration);
```

> Parameters
>   position -> Position to scroll to
>
> offset ---->Desired distance in pixels of position from the top of the
>   view when scrolling is finished
>
> duration-> Number of milliseconds to use for the scroll

Comment: i have try it but replacing the  Log.v(TAG, "Scrolled up"); with my condition to get new entries from the database but it still not working. the scroll up is stop at the last original entry and new entries are identify only after scrolling down and up again.

Comment: actually what happened is that when the   chatAdaptor.notifyDataSetChanged();  is called the listView is jumping to the end of the list. I have tried to call                             chatLinesView.setStackFromBottom(false); so in that case, the listview is jumping to the top of the list.

Comment: Yes just keep the position you want in setSelectionFromTop

Comment: you new suggestion is also not working....once i notify for changes the listview is jumping to the end of the listview. anyway, i read the documentation  of setSelectionFromTop and it say "Sets the selected item and positions the selection y pixels from the top edge of the ListView."  so i dont thing it can help since it talking about y pixels....which i have no way to calculate since each item at the chat can have different size. so you have any other idea how to scroll to the correct positioning after notify changes???

Comment: also the new suggested solution is not working, onne i am calling the notify changes the listvies is jumping to the end of the list and and the smoothScrollToPositionFromTop do nothing !. there is something that i cannot understand. why the simple setSelection is not working? the only thing i need it how to navigate listview into sepcific position programmatically??